# How to remove extensions icons from Chrome toolbar and menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

As we know in the past only extension that has "browser_action:default_icon" in its manifest file was displayed on the Chrome toolbar. But recently, Google Chrome displays icons of all the extensions on its toolbar even if I install old version of the browser. How to disable this feature even removing it from the Chrome source code? (I mean from chrome.dll, resources.pak or another file). I don't mean how to hide the icons by moving them from the toolbar to the Chrome menu. I mean how to remove this feature at all or at least hide unwanted icons both on the toolbar and the menu?

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: Chrome is not open source, you can't modify its source. You can do it for [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

Comment: The quotation from Wikipedia: _"Google releases the majority of Chrome's source code as an open-source project Chromium. A notable component that is not open source is their version of the built-in Adobe Flash Player, called Pepper Flash Player."_

Comment: I have Chromecast icon and I can right click it and it shows the option "Hide from chrome menu"?